# How to correctly set/read query param in url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, query-string

I use React and I've got Filter component, which has some form element like, checkbox, input, select and i when i click button "apply filters" I want to save data from filters in URL and then after reload page just read it from there.

I use [useQueryParams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-query-params#encodequeryparams) to set data in URL. For example filter/shop=ball&shop=phone&shop=apple

How can i translate URL in correct JS Data type. May be do anyone know some npm package for it.

For example i have url  filter/shop=ball&shop=phone&shop=apple&count=123&name=example

And I want to get an object like

```
{
shop: [ball,phone,apple],
count:123,
name:'example"
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: You can make use of - https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseQuery() {
  const qs = window.location.search.replace('?', '')
  const items = qs.split('&')
  return items.reduce((data, item) => {
    const splittedItem = item.split('=')
    const key = splittedItem[0]
    const value = splittedItem.length > 2 ? window.decodeURIComponent(splittedItem.slice(1).join('=')) : splittedItem[1]
    if(data[key] !== undefined) {
      if(!Array.isArray(data[key])) {
        data[key] = [ data[key] ]
      }
      data[key].push(value)
    } else {
      data[key] = value
    }

    return data
  }, {})
}
```